# Does using jquery 1.12.4 (reported as vulnerable) affect SEO?

Tags: seo, jquery

Can jquery 1.12.4 used on a website affect search engine rankings (especially of that of Google)? Several forums and websites have discussed vulnerabilities with this particular version of jquery.

Ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205864/is-there-a-way-to-exploit-jquery-1-12-4-vulnerability

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: The library reference was part of a plugin I am using. However, I am working to test and upgrade to the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As far as I know, Google does not check JavaScript library versions, as that would be a very messy and imprecise business. Plus, the jQuery vulnerability is only in a specific part of the library, so if that part of the library isn't being used, it doesn't come into play anyways.

If your website is being actively used for scams or distributing malware, that can affect your rank of course, but using a library with a medium-security CVE should not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just checked the lighthouse audit report for StackExchange. StackExchange too uses jquery 1.12.4. Interesting :) but reassuring. If not a StackOverflow website, then who's going to rank.